# Trouble Logging In to Website Using Selenium in Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pytest

I am trying to automate a login process to "https://mirentapp.app/" using Selenium in Python, but I'm unable to log in successfully. My goal is to navigate to the page, input credentials, and then retrieve a user token stored in local storage. However, the process seems to halt at the login step, and I can't figure out why the login isn't succeeding.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Initialize the WebDriver (assuming Chrome in this example)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/path/to/chrome/profile")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

# Navigate to the page where you need to perform the login
driver.get("https://qa.mirentapp.net/")
# Wait for the username field to be present
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "email")))

driver.find_element(By.ID, "email").send_keys("YOUR_EMAIL")
password_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, "password")
password_field.send_keys("YOUR_PASSWORD")
password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

**What I've Tried:**

1. Verified the correctness of the login credentials
2. Ensured that the IDs for the email and password fields are correct.
3. Checked for any    potential alerts or pop-ups that might be blocking the login.

**Questions**

1. Are there any common pitfalls or issues with Selenium that could be causing this login failure?
2. Could the issue be related to how I'm handling local storage or session data with the --user-data-dir Chrome option?
3. Any suggestions on how to debug or resolve this issue to successfully log in and retrieve the token from local storage?

Comment: Code works for me, just gives login error of course. But its inputting and passing credentials correctly

Comment: Yes, it works, but when I do this with the correct credentials the login web refresh and it give me an error.